# Why do images and CSS not load despite fast internet?

Tags: windows-8, internet

I have a very fast internet connection (50 MBit/s) and am connected via LAN cable.
Despite that, quite a few websites often don't load CSS or images. When I refresh, mostly it works.

**What might be the reason? And how to solve this problem?**

Find attached two examples, one from [Kicker.de](http://www.kicker.de) (pictures missing)

[image]

and another from [fcn.de](http://www.fcn.de/home/) (CSS not loading)

[image]

My system: Windows 8, i3, Intel HD 4000

Comment: Have you looked at your DNS response time? If the site is loading from different domains, that could be what is slowing you up.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: How would I do that in Win8?

Comment: well, NSLOOKUP checks that you can resolve an IP address, and if it times out then that could be the problem. You'd want to look at the page source to see what URL's the css etc are hosted on